# SQL strict subset of sets

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that represents a graph:

```
| FROM_ID | TO_ID |
-------------------
| 1       | 9     |
| 1       | 8     |
| 1       | 7     |
| 2       | 7     |
| 2       | 8     |
| 3       | 9     |
| 3       | 7     | 
| 4       | 6     |
| 4       | 8     |
```

In the real example there are ~5M rows with ~5k unique FROM and ~100k unique TO

I want to find all pairs (FROM_ID_X, FROM_ID_Y) s.t. the set of TO_ID for each FROM_ID is a strict superset of those for the other FROM_ID.

So in this example I would get:
`(1,2), (1,3)`

To make this more clear:
Each row represents an edge in a graph. Each node in the graph is either of type A or type B. One type A node is connected to one or more type B nodes. I want to find pairs of nodes of type A s.t. one of them points to a strict subset of the other.

using postgres fwiw

Comment: What is `F`? I do not follow. Can you please reformulate your question?

Comment: better? F was just shorthand for from

Comment: but if the set of `TO_ID` is a *strict* superset of those from the the other `FROM_ID`, there are multiple options: simply add one, add all, etc. In other words the result is not deterministic...

Comment: Where does `(1,3)` come from? There is no such row in your sample data

Comment: The set of TO_ID for FROM_ID 1 is {9,8,7}, for FROM_ID 2 its {8,7} for From id 3 its {9,7} and for FROM_ID 4 its {8,6}. Thus, 2 and 3 are both subsets of 1 but 4 is not

Comment: the result should include `(1,4)` as well as 4 has a to_id of 8 and is a subset of `1`.

Comment: @vkp No... The set {9,8,7} is not a strict superset of {8,6}

Comment: yes..you are right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`array_agg`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html) to concatenate the to_id's into an array. Thereafter `self join` this cte to check if one array is a strict superset of the other using the array operator [`<@`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html).

```
with concatenated_to as (
select from_id, array_agg(to_id) as arr_to
from t
group by from_id
)
select c1.from_id,c2.from_id 
from concatenated_to c1
join concatenated_to c2 on c1.from_id<>c2.from_id
where c2.arr_to <@ c1.arr_to
```

[**`Sample Demo`**](http://rextester.com/ZEU8456)

Comment: cool. Running it now. This was my initial idea, but worried about how it performs at scale. If it runs in ~minutes or even hours thats fine. It's a one-time query, but wondering if theres a faster way / what the performance implications of array subsetting it

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select t.from_id, t2.from_id
from (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by from_id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t left join
     (select t.*, count(*) over (partition by from_id) as cnt
      from t
     ) t2
     on t.to_id = t2.to_id and t2.cnt = t.cnt
group by t.from_id, t2.from_id
having count(*) = count(t2.from_id);
```

Comment: getting `ERROR:  column "t.cnt" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function`

Comment: also I'm not sure that this answers the question correctly. Why should the counts be equal in the join?

Comment: @marisbest2 . . . That should be `count(*) = count(t2.from_id)`.  It simply means that all the `t2` rows match.